# Which is the easier and convenient way to make post methods for multiple model instances in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have an `Employee` class that has a couple of instances that are `ForeignKey`s. I am using django rest frame work and I have created also a serializer and the next step is to create a `POST` method to enable creating of an `Employee`. Which method can I use conveniently to achieve this?

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    """
    Model, which holds general information of an employee.

    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='users',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo_logo = models.FileField()
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True) # validators should be a list
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        'hr.Company',
        verbose_name='Company',
        related_name='companies',
        null=True, blank=True,
    )

    marital_status = models.ForeignKey(MaritalStatus)
    identification_type = models.ForeignKey(IdentificationType)
```

### Serializers.py

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    designation = GroupListSerializer()
    # department = GroupListSerializer() 
    # user = UserSerializer()
    # address = AddressSerializer()
    # em_contact = EmergencyContactSerializer()
    # address = EmergencyContactSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['id','user','photo_logo','phone_number','dob', 'gender', 'hr_number', 'company', 'marital_status', 'identification_type',
                    'tax_id_number','joining_date', 'designation', 'department']
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using `CreateAPIView` from Generic views: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview

So, you'll have to add class to your `views.py`. It may look like this:

```
from rest_framework import generics

from .serializers import EmployeeSerializer

class CreateEmployeeView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
```

Also, don't forget to register your view in `urls.py`